# How do I make a Lightning Card title wrap to the next line on a small screen?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using Lightning Card components and a couple of them have rather long titles. All look fine on a desktop, but on a phone, some of the titles are truncated. Is there a way to make the Lightning Card title wrap to multiple lines on a small screen?

```
<lightning:card title="This is a really long title for a Lightning Card">
.
.
.
</lightning:card>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were able to get the Title to wrap on a narrow screen with the following CSS (in the parent component)

```
.THIS .slds-truncate {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell without seeing your code, but Css wise, if you properly scope the element, you can use:

[overflow-wrap](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) and set it to break-word if you want the text displayed over multiple lines.

Additionally, you might want to a@media query in your CSS for this to work on "small" screen only.