# How to wrap lightning-card's title?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-card

We have an LWC and sometimes the title can be really long. I have seen [How do I make a Lightning Card title wrap to the next line on a small screen?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220722/how-do-i-make-a-lightning-card-title-wrap-to-the-next-line-on-a-small-screen) but that did not help.

Any other suggestions?

```
    <lightning-card  variant="Narrow" title={displayText} icon-name="standard:account">
```

here displayText is passed in as a parameter on the Lightning record page:

```
<property label="Display Sub-Text" name="displaySubText" type="String"/>
```

[image]

Update: I wonder if this is the reason why it is not working [Target inner elements of standard Lightning Web Components with CSS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246887/target-inner-elements-of-standard-lightning-web-components-with-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-card/specification) the description of title in lightning card says:

> Placeholder for the card title, which can be represented by a header or h1 element.
> The title is displayed at the top of the card, to the right of the icon.
> Alternatively, use the title attribute if you don't
> need to pass in extra markup in your title.

Using this information, you could use a slot for placing HTML markup instead of an attribute:

```html
<lightning-card  variant="Narrow" icon-name="standard:account">
    <h1 slot="title" class="no-wrap">{displayText}</h1>
</lightning-card>
```

Borrowing the solution from the [mentioned post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220722/how-do-i-make-a-lightning-card-title-wrap-to-the-next-line-on-a-small-screen) in your question, now you can apply CSS to the title:

```css
.no-wrap {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: looked like a feasible idea. Just tried it but unfortunately didn't work for me

Comment: Could you share on what didn't work?

Comment: I made change exactly as suggested above and it made no difference. The title was still truncated.

Comment: hmm, that is strange, I updated the output in the answer

Comment: yes was strange - looks like it is fine now. (I am 100% sure I did a 'empty cache and hard reload' few times before saying it didn't work. Thx again for your time and effort.

Comment: Ah I see, you should [Disable Caching Setting During Development](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/debug_disable_caching.htm).